# React native: stop app music when open app

Tags: android, ios, react-native, audio

I'm developing React Native application and I need to stop phone music (for example, Apple Music or Spotify) when I open my app. Does anybody know how to do so for both platforms?

Comment: On Android you should look at this 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioFocusRequest
it will require a bit of Native code

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is useful for react, but I did find something that looks promising.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/volume-and-earphones

Edit: This may not do what you mean by stop music.

Another resource: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-focus